# How to "start" or "activate" a network with libvirt?

Tags: libvirt

How do you "start" an inactive network using `libvirt`? With `virsh` this would be `net-start <network>`.

I can create a network with [`virNetworkDefineXML`](https://libvirt.org/html/libvirt-libvirt-network.html#virNetworkDefineXML), which will:

> Define an inactive persistent virtual network or modify an existing persistent one from the XML description.

(which is the equivalent of `virsh net-define`), but I don't know how to "start" this newly-created, but inactive network.

I'm using the `libvirt-python` bindings, but knowing the correct C API would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The API is [`virNetworkCreate()`](https://libvirt.org/html/libvirt-libvirt-network.html#virNetworkCreate):**

> Create and start a defined network. If the call succeed the network moves from the defined to the running networks pools.

---

To find this, we can look at the source for `virsh`.  The "net-start" command is defined in [`tools/virsh-network.c`](http://libvirt.org/git/?p=libvirt.git;a=blob;f=tools/virsh-network.c;h=a0f7707b93319655a54c0749933d0011b14ce7d9;hb=HEAD#l784):

```c
static bool
cmdNetworkStart(vshControl *ctl, const vshCmd *cmd)
{
    virNetworkPtr network;
    bool ret = true;
    const char *name = NULL;

    if (!(network = virshCommandOptNetwork(ctl, cmd, &name)))
         return false;

    if (virNetworkCreate(network) == 0) {
        vshPrint(ctl, _("Network %s started\n"), name);
    } else {
        vshError(ctl, _("Failed to start network %s"), name);
        ret = false;
    }
    virNetworkFree(network);
    return ret;
}
```

---

In `libvirt-python`, this means simply calling `.create()` on the network object returned from `.networkDefineXML()`:

```python
conn = libvirt.open('qemu:///system')

# Define a new persistent, inactive network
xml = open('net.xml', 'r').read()
net = conn.networkDefineXML(xml)

# Set it to auto-start
net.setAutostart(True)

# Start it!
net.create()
```